# Sort and Match List Item

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have the following List where each list item has `Start` and `End` values. Please observe that each list item's `End` value matches with next List item's `Start` value.

```
tableItems.Add (new SettingsCellItem() {Start=1000, End=4000});
tableItems.Add (new SettingsCellItem() {Start=4000, End=6000});
tableItems.Add (new SettingsCellItem() {Start=6000, End=8000});
tableItems.Add (new SettingsCellItem() {Start=8000, End=11300});
tableItems.Add (new SettingsCellItem() {Start=11300,End=12000});
```

User is allowed to update only `Start` Values and when user enter new `Start` values, List should be sorted based on `Start` value before it displays again.

Let's assume user updates the second list item from `{Start=4000,End=6000}` to `{Start=140,End=6000}`

```
List<SettingsCellItem> sortedList =tableItems.OrderBy(o=>o.Start).ToList();
```

I got the following output. As you observe End value does not match with Start value anymore.

**Current Output:**

```
{Start=140,  End=6000}
{Start=1000, End=4000}
{Start=6000, End=8000}
{Start=8000, End=11300}
{Start=11300,End=12000}
```

I wonder how could I able to get the following:

**Desired Output**

```
{Start=140,  End=1000}
{Start=1000, End=6000}
{Start=6000, End=8000}
{Start=8000, End=11300}
{Start=11300,End=12000}
```

Comment: What is the code you are using to get the 'Current Output'? Can't you just sort by "Start" property?

Comment: If you know which cell has been updated then you can find a place where to move this cell and update previous or/and next cells after you moved the cell updated by user.

Comment: `sortedList` is my Current output

Comment: if the start of cell is the end of another cell, shouldn't a new user entry modify other cells' starts and ends to get that chain pattern in your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer that comes to mind would be to loop through the new list and update the end values to match the next item's start value. Something like this perhaps

```
public void UpdateEndValues(List<TypeLogSettingsCellItem> list)
 {
    int highestEndValue = list.Max (x => x.End);

    for(int i = 0; i < list.Count -1; i++)
    {
        list[i].End = list[i+1].Start;
    }

    list.Last.End = (list.Last.Start > highestEndValue) ? list.Last.Start : highestEndValue;
}
```

Note that the major difference between my code and the previous answer from pikciu is that mine preserves the final End value, which his/hers will not if the last CellItem is the one that was edited by the user

**Updated:**
@texas pointed out that I was mishandling the case where the new start value is higher than the old highest end value, so I updated my code sample to cover that

Comment: your loop will throw exception for last element :) index out of range :) fix it :P

Comment: No it won't, the loop intentionally doesn't iterate over the last element of the list, note "i < list.Length -1". meaning the highest i will ever be is list.Length - 2, so there will never be on out of range exception

Comment: Fair enough, I deleted my comment since I was mistaken about the edit you made. I'm fine with you not updating your answer, but maybe make a note on it that it is flawed since not everyone checks the comments when the answer is the highest voted one.

Comment: Done. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Kevin, your solution does not cover one case, when user types the biggest value in any of the `Start` value which is even bigger than last element's `End` value. if user types the maximum value then the highest `End` value should be the same with the user entry.

Comment: I have added an update on your answer to cover that case as well.

Comment: Good point, though your edit was actually the wrong logic from what I could tell, so I updated my code to cover that case. So now it either sets the last End value to the last Start value or the previous highest End value, whichever is higher

Answer (score 6):

Update End after sorting by Start?

```
for(int i = 0; i < sortedList.Count - 1; i++)
{
    sortedList[i].End = sortedList[i+1].Start
}
```

Look at @Kevin Wells answer if you don't want to lose End value in case when you edit last element

Example for `Select`:

```
var normalizedList = sortedList.Select(
                              (e, i) => 
                                 new SettingsCellItem() 
                                 {
                                   Start = e.Start, 
                                   End = i < sortedList.Count - 1 
                                       ? sortedList[i+1].Start : e.End
                                 }).ToList()
```

Comment: This has a bug in it which my answer addresses, namely that the final End value could be lost by your code. Think about what would happen if the user edited the last element of the list.